# fql is deprecated for versions v2.1 and higher

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, starling-framework, air-native-extension

I am working on AIR for mobile game .I want to make leader board to show scores. for this i am using Goviral ANE version 3.0.11 of milkmanGame. To get scores i am calling funtion

facebookGraphRequest("fql",function1,{q:"SELECT value,user_id FROM score WHERE user_id= me() AND app_id = 12345"},"GET");

and GVFacebookEvent.FB_REQUEST_FAILED event fire and give error "fql is deprecated for versions v2.1 and higher"

Answer (score 1):

You should upgrade your ANE to the current version (4.6.0).

Milkman Games regularly have to update the ANE to keep up with changes to the Facebook SDK.